# counting all rows and getting rows in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I do two queries, one to get the count of all results and one to get the actual results 9 by 9.
my problem is when i try to get the count of the results the second query get all the rows.

```
$courses = $this->load->model("course")->where("deleted",0);
$courses->where("country",strtolower($country));
$courses->count(); // OK
$courses->offset(($per_page)*9)->limit(9);
$courses->get(); // returns 9 rows from all database (like select * from courses limit 9) without where country=france
```

***my problem is I want to count all the results but I want to get just 9 results*** for pagination purposes

Comment: Show us full code. What is `$courses`??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

```
$courses = $this->db;
```

`$course->get()` will give you full record. If you want count do this:

```
$query = $course->get();
echo $query->num_rows();//will give you row count
```

> **Note**: If you want to get all records also you have you use two
>   separate query for fetching records and getting query.

I would suggest you to use Codeigniter [**Pagination Class**](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

Comment: my problem is I want to count all the results but I want to get just 9 results

Comment: So my solution not working??? you different query for getting count and fetching record

Comment: how can I do two queries ! when i do the seconde query it like the $courses has been flushed. do i have to copy $courses ?

Comment: the pagination Class is just for rendring the View not for bissness logic

Answer (score 0):

Need detail of your problem you can check the last executed query by running

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

And then you will be able to trace it.

Comment: the first query returns the correct count but the second query returns all rows without the where clause !